# How to call Java function from within a XSL file?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-fop, xalan

I am using APACHE FOP to convert my xml file to PDF. I have a XSL file in which I need to call a java function to transform some values read from XML.

I have declared the java class containing the function in the namespace and am calling the static java function as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-  prefixes="java"
  xmlns:dateConversion = "urn:java:com.geonexus.worx.sync.reports.ReportMaker">

<fo:block background-color="yellow" padding="1pt"> 
    <fo:inline padding-left="2pt" display-align="center"> 
        <xsl:value-of     select="dateConversion.convertDate(@dateDetected)"/>                                                  
    </fo:inline>    
</fo:block>
```

However I keep getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] STDERR - ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
[ERROR] STDERR - FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
       :Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(dateConversion.convertDate, [step("attribute", 51)])'.
[ERROR] STDERR - javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
[ERROR] STDERR -    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] STDERR -    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: FOP itself is not an XSLT processor; by default it uses Xalan for XSLT transformations. I guess that you are targeting Xalan with your Java extension. If that is true, you should say so and tag the question with "xalan".

Comment: What happens if you try `<xsl:value-of select="java:com.geonexus.worx.sync.reports.ReportMaker.convertDat‌e(@dateDetected)"/>` , with namespace declaration `xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XALAN, try below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:dateConversion="xalan://com.geonexus.worx.sync.reports.ReportMaker"
  extension-element-prefixes="dateConversion"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dateConversion">

<fo:block background-color="yellow" padding="1pt"> 
    <fo:inline padding-left="2pt" display-align="center"> 
        <xsl:value-of     select="dateConversion:convertDate(@dateDetected)"/>                                                  
    </fo:inline>    
</fo:block>
```

Updating with simple XSL and Java class.

**XSL**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dateConversion="xalan://com.geonexus.worx.sync.reports.ReportMaker"
    extension-element-prefixes="dateConversion" exclude-result-prefixes="dateConversion">

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <abcd>
            <xsl:value-of select="dateConversion:convertDate('2005-03-02')" />
        </abcd>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Java Class:**

```
package com.geonexus.worx.sync.reports;

public class ReportMaker {

    public static String convertDate(String date) {

        return date.replaceAll("-", ":");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><abcd>2005:03:02</abcd>
```

Comment: Please test your answers before posting.